# How to optimize mongo query on large collection around 30M?

Tags: mongodb, ruby-on-rails-4, mongodb-query

> In my application we record user activity in session analytics
> collection, till date, there is around 30M records on our collection
> mainly 20M created on Feb 2018 to May 2018. When we count active user
> on given time period i.e Jan 1 2018 to May 20 2018, Server return
> Timeout error because query execute in 60+ seconds. Our application
> made in Rails and my query is

```
> `SessionAnalytic.collection.aggregate([
{
  "$match" => {
    "start_date" => {
      "$gte" => options[:start_date],
      "$lte" => options[:end_date]
    },
    "community_uuid" => options[:community_uuid],
    "user_type"      => options[:user_type]
  }
},
{"$group": {"_id": "$user_uuid" } },
{"$count": 'total_users' }
]).first`
```

> There is indexing on community_uuid, user_type and start_date fields.
> Anyone can suggest why it is taking huge amount of time for execution.
> As I know MongoDB can handle large amount of data.

Comment: What are your indexes and what's the spec of your servers? Please also provide some example documents.

Comment: index({community_uuid: 1, user_type: 1, start_date: 1}, {background: true})
  index({community_uuid: 1, start_date: 1}, {background: true})
  index({community_uuid: 1, start_date: 1, user_uuid: 1}, {background: true})
This is indexes on session_analytics collections and server plan on Heruku is 40GB hdd and 2GB RAM.

Comment: { "_id" : ObjectId("5a4d4cb082a32f000447224b"), "start_date" : ISODate("2018-01-04T03:05:44.580+05:30"), "last_active_at" : ISODate("2561-01-04T02:36:30.000+05:30"), "event_name" : "Session", "platform" : "ios", "community_uuid" : "87d1bc72730241391b65cf7d", "user_type" : 1, "user_uuid" : "6e989104acf31ef84a43c097", "ip_address" : "172.58.39.74", "created_at" : ISODate("2018-01-04T03:05:44.580+05:30"), "country" : null}  This is the format of docs in collection

Answer (score 0):

I'm not MongoDB expert, but i know how SQL indexes works and it should be quite similar.

In my opinion 30M is big amount of records, but Mongo should handle it - but again it depends. 
Most important question is, do you have single index that contains 3 fields or 3 separated indexes? - you should have one index with 3 fields (or even 4). Also this index should contains $user_uuid field. Why? Because it's used in group by clause, so if $user_uuid is not indexed, then after match MongoDB need to fetch $user_uuid from source collection for each record - and it will be slow.

If it still wouldn't work then i would write some code that aggregate all activities for all users per single day and change your query so as to use pre grouped data.

Comment: We have single index that contains 3 fields. There isn't an index on user_uuid because we need to calculate active user as well as mongo $group not worked on index, only $match and $sort pipeline operator work on index, that's stuck point.

Comment: As you suggested in 2nd approach we did same but the problem is active user count, we can't calculate it or store their count, because if we take more than 1 day range of data then there would be duplicate user_uuid which should eliminate from actual count of active users. We are following Time series base approach where we divide data hourly basis to reduce duplicate user an hour. But it is not helping enough because of user_uuid.